# Hover transitions not working when changing relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, sass

Attempting to add a transition time when hovering over an absolutely positioned div that adds 20px to the top. The hover effect is working, but the transition time is not taking effect.

SCSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all 5s;
  &:hover {
    top: 20px;
  }
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/KevinM818/pen/YYZqKY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set initial value of top property to 0px.

```
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: all .5s;
  top: 0px;
  &:hover {
    top: 20px;
  }
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opZxzo